# FPDF: Printing the text from another PHP echo

Tags: pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm trying to figure out how to print out dynamic content without creating a physical TXT file to print the data from.

In other words, I'm calling `mytext.php` and writing the contents out ... `mytext.php` looks like this:

`<?php echo "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";`

And the PDF is generated with literally ALL of that within the text ... so `<?php echo "Lorem..."`

What's the best way to print dynamic content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is assemble the dynamic content (query the db, using post-variables ...) from within the script that generates the pdf.

If that is not necessary and the php-script you're calling outputs plain text, you could use output buffering.

There is a question that has already been asked here that holds the answer:
[Read echo'ed output from another php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631388/read-echoed-output-from-another-php-file).

So basically, you put the output in a variable and using the FPDF Write, Cell or Multicell-function, place it inside your pdf.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the way to go too! Thanks!